# Bootstrap - columns mapping (similar to row-cols-*)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I have a question about Bootstrap. Is there simple solution for rendering array of elements in columns automatically, that works similar to **row-cols-***?

Current code:

```
 <div className="row row-cols-3">
      {array.map((item) => (
        <div className="col" key={item.id}>
          <div class="card" style={{ width: "12rem", height: "12rem" }}> 
            <div class="card-body">
              {item.name} 
            </div> 
           </div>
        </div>
      ))}
 </div>
```

And that renders in this order:
[image]

But I want layout to be like this:
[image]

I tried with flex order but I can't work it out in simple way...

Comment: @Zim Yes, they do.

Comment: How about adding the add the odd numbered column in a row (<div class="row">) and  even numbered in another row?

Comment: @Zim Actually that's it about HTML, I have .row that should have .col, but since it's dynamic I can't hardcode it

Comment: @VikramKumar Didn't understand where to add that?

Comment: Just extracted React component containing bootstrap card layout, something like this:
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
    {item.name}
  </div>
</div>
@Zim

Comment: Yes, sorry for that, will edit that in question so you can undestand @Zim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are basically 2 options.

**1** - Use `flex-column` and limit the height of the flexbox container (`row`) to roughly double the height of the columns. This is assuming you want 2 rows. If you want 3 rows you would triple the height, 4 rows quadruple the height, etc..

```
      <div className="row row-cols-3 flex-column" style={{ height: "26rem" }}>
              {array.map((item) => (
                <div className="col d-flex justify-content-center py-2" key={item}>
                 <div className="card" style={{ width: "12rem", height: "12rem" }}> 
                    <div className="card-body">
                      {item} 
                    </div> 
                   </div>
                </div>
              ))}
      </div>
```

2 - Use `card-columns` (Bootstrap 4 only) instead of the grid. CSS multi-column layout naturally order top to bottom instead of left to right.

```
       <div className="card-columns mx-auto">
              {array.map((item) => (
                <div className="card" key={item} style={{ width: "12rem", height: "12rem" }}>
                    <div className="card-body">
                      {item} 
                    </div> 
                </div>
              ))}
       </div>
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/qtcJ7oWEDX)

Comment: Thanks! First approach works! 
Do you think there is no other solution without hardcoding the height?
Anyway thank you very much!

Comment: Yeah I think that's the only way